# find the same object from two images which contain two crowds of such similar objects

Tags: deep-learning, sift, surf, siamese-network

this is more like a brainstorming topic, any suggestion will be welcome.
Suppose there are two drone flying over a sea area. There is a big group of ships (following picture 1). each drone will capture the area only one time from different angle and the picture may not contain all the ships(picture 2 and picture 3).

[Figure 1. overall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH4LB.png)

[Figure 2. the picture captured by drone 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKrZu.png)

[Figure 3. the picture captured by drone 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88rly.png)

I am thinking a way (no matter the traditional way or deep learning) to associate those spotted ships, i.e. ship4 and ship6.

PS: I have tried to use Siamese Network from another stackoverflow topic or Traditional techniques like SIFT SURF etc.

I hope there is a robust end2end way to find out the same objects from crowds.